# Parse any value to enum

Tags: angular, typescript

On an angular 12 app I have the enum:

```
export enum Policy {
  Admin,
  Manager
}
```

I try to define a variable of type Policy as follows:

```
let policy: Policy = Policy[route.data.policy as string];
```

The type of `route.data.policy` is `any`. But I get the error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

How can to parse the value of route.data.policy which would be `'Admin'` or `'Manager'` to enum?

Comment: TL;DR: `let policy: Policy = Policy[route.data.policy as keyof typeof Policy];` [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=10&pln=9&pc=3#code/MYewdgzgLgBATiArlApjAvDA3gKBjAEwEMoiAubPfGABxABsBLYATwoHIBBAgW0bHZUAvjiEBuHCgAedOLBRhEPGAAUGzFpXzc+YADRUAskTBEA5ijiiYOeilh0mrCmqebMrjQG0EyFADpiUn9HDRgiCBgAaxQWEAAzGCgWGhQE1XVWAF0xIA)

Answer (score 0):

What if you type `route.data.policy` as a `Policy`? Then you can just have,

```
let policy: Policy = route.data.policy;
```

Comment: You mean `let policy: Policy = route.data.policy as Policy`? I didn't know I could parse it that way.

Comment: That actually might work, but what I meant was to go to wherever you define route.data.policy and type that field as a Policy.

Comment: I can't. I am getting `route.data.policy` from an Angular method.

Comment: Ah I see. My mistake. I recommend @Heretic Monkey's solution, then.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a value to the keys so `Manager = 'Manager'` this converts the enum so it takes strings in the `[]` brackets instead of the default numbers based on index.